# Is the trace of logarithm of convolution between two matrices equal to the sum of trace of logarithm of the matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, functional-analysis

Consider two square matrices which are functions of $\bar x_i$: $A(\bar x_1,\bar x_2)$ and $B(\bar x_1,\bar x_2)$. Is there an identity that looks like $\text{Tr}\{\ln{\int d\bar x_2 A(\bar x_1,\bar x_2)B(\bar x_2,\bar x_3)}\}=\text{Tr}\{\ln{A(\bar x_1,\bar x_3)}\}+\text{Tr}\{\ln{B(\bar x_1,\bar x_3)}\}$? 
I know that it is true without the integral but I am not sure when there is a convolution integral between the two matrices.